# Informix - Tools to export and import triggers and stored procedures

Tags: informix

Folks : If this is a repetitive question, please raise the flag so that i will delete the question.

I am currently looking for some Informix tools which can be used for exporting the triggers and stored procedures from one database and importing the same into an another database. Requesting help & pointers on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB-Schema (`dbschema`) is the standard answer:

- `dbschema -d dbname -f stored_procedure` to export a specific stored procedure.
- Use `all` to specify all stored procedures.

Triggers are on a specific table: getting the schema for that table will include the triggers.  There isn't a way to get the triggers alone.

> USAGE:
>
> ```
>   dbschema { [-q] [-t tabname] [-s user] [-p user] [-r rolename] [-f procname]
>            [-hd tabname] -d dbname [-w passwd] [-seq sequence] [-l [num]]
>            [-u [ia] udtname [all]] [-it [Type]] [-ss [-si]] [filename]
>            [-sl length] [-nw] }
>            { [-q] -c [-ns] [filename] }
>
>
>   -q      Suppress the db version from header
>
>   -t      table name or "all" for all tables
>
>   -s      synonyms created by user name
>           or "all" for all users
>
>   -p      permissions granted to user name
>           or "all" for all users
>
>   -r      create and grant of the role
>           or "all" for all roles :Not a valid option for SE
>
>   -f      SPL routine name
>           or "all" for all SPL routines
>
>
>   -hd     Histograms of the distribution for columns of
>           of a specified table, a specific table column,
>           or "all" for all tables.
>
>   -d      database name
>
>   -w      database password
>
>   -seq    generate sequence specific syntax
>
>   -u      Prints the definitions of user-defined data types
>
>   -ui     Prints the definitions of user-defined data types,
>           including type inheritance
>
>   -ua     Prints the definitions of user-defined data types,
>           including all functions and casts defined over a type
>
>   -u all  Directs dbschema to include all the tables
>           in the display of distributions
>
>   -it     Type of isolation can be DR, CR, CS, RR or LC
>
>   -l      set lock mode to wait [number] optional
>
>   -ss     generate server specific syntax
>
>   -si     excludes the generation of index storage clauses for
>           non-fragmented tables
>
>   -sl     the maximum length (in bytes) of unformatted CREATE TABLE and ALTER FRAGMENT statements.
>
>           filename is the name
>           of file that the SQL
>           script goes in.
>
>   -c      generate storage space and logical log definitions
>
>
>   -ns     generate commands in non-sql format
>
>   -nw     generate file with no specified owner
> ```